# Laravel Eloquent - Diferencias eager loading

Tags: laravel, eloquent

¿Qué diferencia hay entre estas dos consultas en cuanto a rendimiento, etc.?:

```
Users::query()
    ->with('roles')
    ->get();

Users::query()
    ->get()
    ->load(['roles']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Laravel dispone de un par métodos para, al crear una consulta, volcar los query bindings actuales y SQL. Ref [Database: Query Builder # Debugging](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#debugging).

Con ellos notarás que no hay diferencia entre ambas consultas traducidas a mysql, y en cuanto a  rendimiento prácticamente tampoco, simplemente que con la segunda puedes cargar opcionalmente la relación mas tarde:

1.

```
DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
User::query()
    ->with('roles')
    ->get();
Log::debug(DB::getQueryLog());

/*
array (
    0 => 
    array (
    'query' => 'select * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null',
    'bindings' => 
    array (
    ),
    'time' => 0.59,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
    'query' => 'select `roles`.*, `role_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `role_user`.`role_id` as `pivot_role_id`, `role_user`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`, `role_user`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at` from `roles` inner join `role_user` on `roles`.`id` = `role_user`.`role_id` where `role_user`.`user_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15)',
    'bindings' => 
    array (
    ),
    'time' => 0.62,
    ),
)  
*/
```

2. 

```
DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
User::query()
    ->get()
    ->load(['roles']);
Log::debug(DB::getQueryLog());

/*
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'query' => 'select * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null',
    'bindings' => 
    array (
    ),
    'time' => 0.58,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'query' => 'select `roles`.*, `role_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `role_user`.`role_id` as `pivot_role_id`, `role_user`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`, `role_user`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at` from `roles` inner join `role_user` on `roles`.`id` = `role_user`.`role_id` where `role_user`.`user_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15)',
    'bindings' => 
    array (
    ),
    'time' => 0.61,
  ),
)  
*/
```

Comment: Me había parecido que no había una diferencia sustancial. Gracias por el trazado.

Comment: @Orici Vale. También puedes usar en desarrollo un par de paquetes externos que sirven para debugar queries (entre otras cosas): el clásico [barryvdh/laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar), [dmitry-ivanov/laravel-db-profiler](https://github.com/dmitry-ivanov/laravel-db-profiler) o [itsgoingd/clockwork](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork).